# Grails 3 change cell display style in in f:table

Tags: grails

I am new with Grails. I like the idea of all views can be generated with ease, however now I am facing some issues when I want to customize the display style of date of birth column in `f:table` (as I understood this comes from fields plugin). The value of the column shown as

`2017-09-27 00:00:00 ICT`

Some portion of the `_table.gsp`

```
<g:each in="${collection}" var="bean" status="i">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
            <g:each in="${domainProperties}" var="p" status="j">
                <g:if test="${j==0}">
                    <td><g:link method="GET" resource="${bean}"><f:display bean="${bean}" property="${p.name}" displayStyle="${displayStyle?:'table'}" theme="${theme}"/></g:link></td>
                </g:if>
                <g:elseif test="${p.name instanceof java.util.Date}">
                    <td>Some style here</td>
                </g:elseif>
                <g:else>
                    <td><f:display bean="${bean}" property="${p.name}"  displayStyle="${displayStyle?:'table'}" theme="${theme}"/></td>
                </g:else>
            </g:each>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
```

Do I have to override the `_table.gsp` of the plugin ? If yes how ? Or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to implement, see docs [here](http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html)

One way of doing it is to create a file named `_displayWrapper.gsp` in a subdirectory named the same as the field your'e trying to customize so e.g. if your domain is called `Person` & the date field is `dob` you'd create the following:

```
/views/person/dob/_displayWrapper.gsp
```

Then in _displayWrapper.gsp you have access to a bunch of fields such as the entire bean or in this case you probably just want the value so something like the following:

```
<g:formatDate date="${value}" format="EEE d MMM yyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

This should render the date field in the format specified in the `f:table`.

Comment: The above works for my `index.gsp` which contains `f:table`. However in my `show.gsp` it contains `f:display`. Even after I added `/views/_fields/registration/dob/_displayWrapper.gsp` the displayed date of birth is still `2017-09-28 00:00:00 ICT`. Any idea?

Comment: Create `/views/person/dob/_displayWidget.gsp` with same contents as `_displayWrapper.gsp`